# Solr: ranking of results when querying multiple shards

Tags: solr

If I'm querying across two shards and first shard returned 10 rows and second one returned 100 rows, how is the combined result set ranked? Will I end up with results from first shard (the one with least result) appearing first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When each of the shard returns result for a given query, the results are sorted by the similarity score for each document. The similarity score is a relative measure of how well the document matches to the search query.

Now these results from different shards are merged by the similarity score and presented to the user/application. The similarity scores are calculated within shards before the merge of results happen.

You can include parameters `&shard.info=true` and `fl=*,score` into the query and see the result. Then observe what is the `maxScore` returned by each shard and look at each document with score. You will get the insight how the result are merged.